# Generate a folder inside dist with my current working Git branch name . we are currently using angular Js and webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js

we want to Test each developer changes individually by creating a new URL for every ticket in DEV environment.
So once we build the code we want a folder to be generated inside DIST folder to with git branch name to deploy the whole Folder on dev server which generates a new URL with the git branch name in the URL